# Calculate $E\left(\tilde Y_{k}^{2}\right)$ where $ \tilde Y_{k}=\int_{(2(k-1)+\frac{1}{2}) \pi}^{\left(2 k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi} \cos s d \Theta(s)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, distribution-theory

Let $B(t)$ be a 1-dimensional Brownian motion. Define a sequence of random variables $\left\{Y_{k}\right\}_{k \geq 0}$ by
$$
Y_{k}= \int_{\left(2(k-1)+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi}^{\left(2 k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi} \cos s d B(s) .
$$
$\left\{Y_{k}\right\}_{k \geq 1}$ is a sequence of independent random variables, because of the independence of the increments of the Brownian motion on disjoint intervals. Moreover, each $Y_{k}$ is normally distributed with mean zero and variance
$$
E\left(Y_{k}^{2}\right)=\int_{\left(2(k-1)+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi}^{\left(2 k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi} \cos ^{2} s d s=\pi
$$
I would now define another sequence of random variables $\left\{\tilde Y_{k}\right\}_{k \geq 0}$ by
$$
\tilde Y_{k}= \int_{\left(2(k-1)+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi}^{\left(2 k+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi} \cos s d \Theta(s) .
$$
where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function with the distributional derivative $\dot \Theta=\delta$. Is $\left\{\tilde Y_{k}\right\}_{k \geq 0}$ still a sequence of independent random variables? What is $E\left(\tilde Y_{k}^{2}\right)$?

Comment: From what’s given in question, it looks like $\tilde{Y}_k$ are deterministic values. Moreover, most of them are zero.

Comment: Stieltjès integral with regard to $d\Theta$ is just evaluation at $0$ provided $0$ is inside the interval of integration. Amm $\tilde{Y}_k$ are all null, excepted $\tilde{Y}_0=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Could you add any details to your comments please? Intuitively I understood, but I can't explain it mathematically.